# What is an affordable cheap Linux box you could recommend?

Tags: desktop, linux

I am looking to build a ssh tunnel device that runs linux. The device is on 24/7 and will act mainly as a tunnel for me to ssh into my intranet at home.

This device needs to have the following specs:

1. Compatible with linux
2. Wifi card included
3. Able to run 24/7 without overheating
4. Costing under 200 USD.

I am aware of Raspberry Pi but I am also open to suggestions. What would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would just go with a raspberry pi, more specifically, the [RPi 3 Model B](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CD5VC92) Along with a USB wifi dongle such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FWMEFES).

Cost totals out to about **$49 USD** ($40 for the RPi and $9 for the wifi dongle).

*RPi's are capable of running 24/7, as mentioned [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=60362).*

The main reasons why I would prefer a RPi are:

- It is cheaper, compared to the other options provided.
- The support communities are much larger and documentation is widely available.
- It is capable of being used for SSH.

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend the [UDOO Family](http://www.udoo.org) or the [Odroid Family](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/main.php) (Both came with their own Ubuntu flavor).

> 2. Wifi card included
> 3. Able to run 24/7 without overheating

If this works 24/7 you could damage the Wifi card; as you need for WiFi, you could instead buy an USB Wifi Module like [this](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G137447734369) or [this](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G145431421052). The main attraction of the Pi 3 are the Wi-fi and Bluetooth, but in this case maybe is more important to invest in RAM, a best processor and heatsink.

For your budget an excellent investment would be the **Odroid XU4**

Processor: Samsung Exynos5422 Cortex™-A15 2Ghz and Cortex™-A7 Octa core

CPUs: Mali-T628 MP6(OpenGL ES 3.0/2.0/1.1 and OpenCL 1.1 Full profile)

RAM: 2Gbyte LPDDR3 RAM PoP stacked

USB: 2xUSB 3.0 Host, 1 x USB 2.0 Host

Ethernet: Gigabit Ethernet port

Size: 82 x 58 x 22 mm approx.(including cooling fan) **<--- This is a BIG plus.**

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a [Parallella](https://www.parallella.org/) board.
As mentioned above in regards to running wifi 24/7 and possible damage, you can always run an inexpensive Atheros based USB wifi dongle.

As stated on Parallella's page:

18-core credit card sized computer

• #1 in energy efficiency @ 5W

• 16-core Epiphany RISC SOC

• Zynq SOC (FPGA + ARM A9)

• Gigabit Ethernet

• 1GB SDRAM

• Micro-SD storage

• Up to 48 GPIO pins

• HDMI, USB (optional)

• Open source design files

• Runs Linux

• >10,000 boards shipped

• Starting at $99

Answer (score 1):

Vilros makes pre-assembled kits for Beaglebones and Pis:

- [Beaglebone Black Starter Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P6TV9V4) - Comes with pre-configured SD card, cables, and a case. No setup necessary.
- [Raspberry Pi 3 Starter Kit](http://www.vilros.com/raspberry-pi-3-complete-starter-kit-clear-case-edition.html) - Comes with pre-configured SD card, working wifi and bluetooth, cables and a case. No setup necessary.

Personally I'd go for the Beaglebone, they're a bit beefier than the Pi. On the other hand the Pi has a very large support community.

The Vilros kits are great, you don't have to mess with anything, really, just turn them on out-of-the-box and you're ready to go.

Alternatively, you could just buy a used, cheap laptop and throw Ubuntu on it. Even [new ones are close to your price range](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2371334,00.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I'd totally go with x86 over ARM. And If you aren't that picky you can spec out what Jeff Atwood calls a scooter computer - these seem to be [systems with 'laptop' class internals](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-scooter-computer/), often of older models, designed for digital signage. They're cheap, and actually pretty well built compared to some random ARM SBC

A minimal speced varient of [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/QOTOM-projector-computer-hardware-mini-pc-Q305p-desktop-computer-for-bulk/108231_32767188260.html) should work - I run a NUC class machine with a similar processor without the big aluminium/industrial case and it hardly even runs warm. Looks like 2gb/32gb would run you 150USD + shipping, Which should be under your budget. Ars technica uses another model as a [router](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/01/numbers-dont-lie-its-time-to-build-your-own-router/) and they haven't had heating issues.

Also, ARM processors don't have the same level of support, and often have janky wifi.This has proper antenna ports and mini PCIe so, its a much better/flexible bet